# Small dataframe after a join is in a large number of partitions, is this not affecting the efficiency?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

**Config**:

I have an EMR cluster with 6 r5.24xlarge nodes and one master node of same config (96 vCore, 768 GiB memory, EBS only storage,EBS Storage,6000 GiB).

I was running my script using spark-submit, however noticed that this was taking a very long time and ending with Java heapspace errors. To debug, I opened an EMR notebook and was running the script line by line.

Problem:

I have 2 dataframes, DF1 and DF2. DF1 has inputs to be looked in DF2, an inverted index.

DF1:

| NAME | KEYWORD |
| --- | --- |
| Michael | mich |
| Michael | mica |

DF2:

| KEYWORD | list_of_places |
| --- | --- |
| mic | [A,B,C...] |
| mike | [P,Q,R...] |
| mich | [S,T,U...] |

DF2 is a very large dataframe, roughly 30M rows (this is an inverted index), compared to DF1 which has around 10k records. I need to join both and get the list_of_places from DF2, and some more operations on this.

`result=df1.join(df2,df1.KEYWORD==df2.KEYWORD,'left')`

After joining, `result.show()` gave me just 65 records. I look at the NumPartitions() like this:

result.rdd.getNumPartitions() and I see 681.

My questions are:

1. Does this mean, these 65 records are split in 681 places in the EMR cluster ?
2. Isn't this bad for efficiency ? Just doing a result.show() takes around 5 minutes on a large cluster.
3. What's the best thing I should do to improve the speed. I thought it makes sense to keep this small set on to one partition. So, I did `result=result.coalesce(1)`. However, `result.show()` takes almost the same or more time as before!